# Doubt about computing running time / time complexity of a function in Python

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, python

I am learning about time complexity now, and I am working with BST (Binary Search Trees).

This question needs some context and this is a follow up post to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803603/computing-the-running-time-of-a-given-function-in-python). Basically, I would like to compute the time complexity of the function below.
The function below refers to a BinarySearchTree where 'u.l' represents the left child of 'u' and 'u.r' represents the right child of 'u'. Additionaly, 'u.p' represents the parent of 'u' and 'self.r' represents the root of our binary search tree.

```
def remove_node(self,u):                                
    if u.r == None or u.l == None: self.splice(u)       
    else:                                               
        w = u.r                                         
        while w.l != None:                              
            w = w.l
    u.x = w.x                                           
    self.splice(w)
```

In the post I linked, we showed that `splice(self,u)` is a function with `O(1)` time-complexity and thus every statement that uses this function only will also have `O(1)` time complexity. Being aware of this, the best case scenario will be obviously when we enter the first `if` statement and in this case we will have that `remove_node` function is `O(1)` time-complexity (since `u.x = w.x` and `self.splice(w)` are also `O(1)` procedures).

With this being said, we must now study the worst case scenario, which is when we enter the `else` statement instead of the `if` statement. `w = u.r` is an atributtion and so it is `O(1)` in time complexity.

And now is where my trouble begins. The main question here is: How many times will be `while` cycle run? Well, this one is obvious. It will run as much times as the number of nodes in the left path of `u.r` to the end of the tree. But how would one translate this into time-complexity? Because we might have a BST such that `u.r == None` and thus the `while` cycle will run 0 times, but we might also have a BST such that `u.r != None` and in this case the `while` cycle will run a total of `n`times, where `n` represents the number of nodes to the left of `u.r` and its left descendants.

Below I give two examples of how many times the while cycle would run in this scenarios:

```
          u      
            \ 
             u.r
              /
           u.r.l                   => The while cycle will run 4 times
          /    \
     u.r.l.l   u.r.l.r
     /
u.r.l.l.l
```

But there are other examples. How would one determine the time complexity of this function? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say that this function has a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(h)$, where $h$ is the [height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) of the BST.

You could be more precise and say that it is a $\Theta(h)$ in the worst case. This means that the complexity will never be more than linear in the height, but adds that this linear case can be reached (even if not every time as you have stated).

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cal{O}(h)$, where $h$ is the height of the node $\texttt{u.r}$ we sent as an argument? Or am I making some confusion?

Comment: Sure, that's true, but in the worst case, the height of `u.r` is one less than the height of `u`, so it does not bring any interesting information. Do not try to be too specific when computing time complexity as long as you do not miss the worst case (and sometimes the average case).

Comment: That's right! Sorry, I guess my mathemathical instincts don't let me be not too specific ahhah

Comment: Sorry to bother again @Nathaniel , but I can't see how it is $\Theta(h)$ in the worst case (?). In my thinking, it should be $\Theta(a)$ in the worst case, where $a$ is the height of the node `u.r.l` where $h = a+2$ (in the worst case `u` would be the root of the tree)

Comment: The [Landau's notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (theta or big oh) are asymptotic notations. As such, they don't care about additionnal constants. That means that in the worst case, where $h = a + 2$, then $\Theta(a) = \Theta(h)$.

Answer (score 4):

While Nathaniel's answer is obviously right, there is something else to consider: Do the operations that you perform change the shape of your tree? I binary tree with 1000 nodes could have a height of 10, or it could be degenerated to a linked list with a height of 1,000. That would happen if you have a naive implementation of "add a node" and add 1,000 nodes in sorted order.

So what is the height of your average tree, based on the algorithms that you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How am I supossed to determine the height of my average tree?

Comment: Is the binary tree a **balanced** binary tree, perhaps an AVL tree or red-black tree? Otherwise, if it is an arbitrary tree, can you assume any input is equally likely, or will an attack attempt to induce the worst-case?

Comment: It is an arbitrary binary search tree, so I believe any input is equally likely, altought I feel like considering the worst-case is the best option